# How can I use my Windows 7 computer to share WiFi connection with PCs that don't have wireless?

Tags: wireless-networking, lan, internet-sharing

Long story short: modem and wireless router are downstairs and we're having a LAN party where some visitors don't have wireless. There's no way to run the length of cabling required, so looking for options. My Windows 7 Home Premium PC has a wireless-n connection, and I'd like to see if I can use it as a "hub" or switch of sorts, running an ethernet cable out of the back and into a switch, then splitting off to the other PCs.

Is this an option? I know with Internet sharing, you can set up your PC as a wireless access point, but I want to do the opposite.

Comment: Plug your Win 7 PC and all the other computers into a switch and set-up [ICS](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-vista/Using-ICS-Internet-Connection-Sharing) (Internet Connection Sharing) among them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not think there is a serious option for doing this. If there is a way there would still be too much traffic that would certainly cause issues with gaming. I assume for this LAN party you must need Internet access also otherwise you would not need to connect to the router/modem, just the switch you mentioned. Your best bet would be to just get some wireless adapters for these other endpoints ($5-$20 each). Or you could get another wireless router/access point to receive the signal and plug the devices into that.

Comment: Yeah, for the cost the USB WLAN cards are a viable option.

Comment: I don't know about your Internet speed but you may still see some lag with multiple people playing on one connection.